# What is the optimal build for maximum undead minions of a Wizard/Cleric at 10th level?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, optimization, undead, necromancy

I'm building an evil necromancer priest at 10th level, and am looking at the Necromancy school for the Wizard levels and Death domain for the cleric levels. This character would lean more on spells and undead minions than on front-line fighting.

What race and class level combinations would provide the most undead minions and DPR in combat, while focusing on the theme of necromancy (Decay, undead minions, etc).

I'm looking for most undead minions primarily, with DPR secondary.

Comment: @MarkTO is it important to you that the character be multiclassed?  If you can get more minions/DPR out of one or the other, would you prefer that?  If they must be multiclassed, do you have some minimum required amount of multiclassing, or is a 1/9 split acceptable?  Also, does quality of minions matter to you at all?  Ability to buff minions?

Comment: Could you clarify what, if any, features you are hoping to take advantage of from these two classes (for example, were you hoping to take advantage of Chanel Divinity)? Also, do you have any information about the stats of this character yet (will you be using standard point buy, rolling for stats, or what)? Are you looking for consistent DPR, or "burst" damage (the ability to do lots of damage infrequently)? Is it important to your character concept whether you or your minions are the ones doing damage?

Comment: I'd recommend simply removing the DPR requirement in order to make this something that can be addressed. The DPR for minions is going to be heavily reliant on factors too broad to factor in. Enemy you're fighting, ranged capability, AC, buffs you can get, spell selections and more.